# \babelhyphenation: why does rasing a penalty lead to a break?

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation, german, discretionary

Feeding

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\textwidth=104.2mm
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}%%% according to the documentation of dehyph-exptl.
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\newcommand{\parComp}{\Umathchar"2"2"02225 }%%% standard ‖ as a binary operator (usually, it is a relation defined as the symbol itself)
% \babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{Zu|stands|ma|schi|nen}%% set the preferences of the hyphenation points in „Zustandsmaschinen“  (German for the plural “state machines”)
% {
%   {}, {},                 % Zu
%   {pre=-,penalty=50,data=2},
%   {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, % stands
%   {pre=-,penalty=50,data=9}, % we wish to have penalty=49. But 50 (default) would also do for this MWE.
%   {}, {},                 % ma
%   {pre=-,penalty=50,data=12}, % we wish to have penalty=51. But penalty=50 would also do for this MWE.
%   {}, {}, {}, {},         % schi
%   {pre=-,penalty=51,data=17},
%   {}, {}, {}              % nen
% }% the arithmetic mean of the penalties is 50.25
\begin{document}%
\noindent
Wir definieren die Komposition \((\Delta_1,\Sigma_1^0)\parComp(\Delta_i,\Sigma_2^0)\) der Zustandsmaschinen zu einer Zustandsmaschine mit
\end{document}
```

to `lualatex` doesn't introduce any breaks within a word.  However, if we raise the penalty for the hyphenation position “Zustandmaschi-nen” a little bit by uncommenting

```
\babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{Zu|stands|ma|schi|nen}%% set the preferences of the hyphenation points in „Zustandsmaschinen“
{
  {}, {},                 % Zu
  {pre=-,penalty=50,data=2},
  {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, % stands
  {pre=-,penalty=50,data=9}, % we wish to have penalty=49. But 50 (default) would also do for this MWE.
  {}, {},                 % ma
  {pre=-,penalty=50,data=12}, % we wish to have penalty=51. But penalty=50 would also do for this MWE.
  {}, {}, {}, {},         % schi
  {pre=-,penalty=51,data=17},
  {}, {}, {}              % nen
}% the arithmetic mean of the penalties is 50.25
```

, we do get a break exactly there. Below, the left side shows the output of the code above without `\babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{…}{…}`, and the right side shows the output of the code with  `\babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{…}{…}`:

[image: diffpdf output]

1. Why does this happen?
2. Who is the culprit?
3. What to do to ensure that if introducing

   ```
   \babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{Zu|stands|ma|schi|nen}%% set the preferences of the hyphenation points in „Zustandsmaschinen“
   {
     {}, {},                 % Zu
     {pre=-,penalty=50,data=2},
     {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, % stands
     {pre=-,penalty=49,data=9},
     {}, {},                 % ma
     {pre=-,penalty=51,data=12},
     {}, {}, {}, {},         % schi
     {pre=-,penalty=51,data=17},
     {}, {}, {}              % nen
   }% the arithmetic mean of the penalties is 50.25
   ```

   leads to breaking the previously not broken “Zustandsmaschinen” at all, the hyphenation would be “Zustands-maschinen”?

By the way, a similar situation can occur with the singular word “Zustandsmaschine” (German for “state machine”):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\textwidth=108.39mm
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
% \babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{Zu|stands|ma|schi|ne}%% set the preferences of the hyphenation points in „Zustandsmaschine“
% {
%   {}, {},                 % Zu
%   {pre=-,penalty=50,data=2},
%   {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, % stands
%   {pre=-,penalty=49,data=9},
%   {}, {},                 % ma
%   {pre=-,penalty=51,data=12},
%   {}, {}, {}, {},         % schi
%   {pre=-,penalty=51,data=17},
%   {}, {}                  % ne
% }% the arithmetic mean of the penalties is 50.25
\begin{document}\noindent
Eine Menge \(M\subseteq A\) von Aktionen stellt ein \emph{Angebot} für eine Zustandsmaschine in einem Zustand \(\sigma\) dar.
Das Angebot wird angenommen, wenn in dem

\noindent
Eine Menge \(M\subseteq A\) von Aktionen stellt ein \emph{Angebot} für eine Zustandsmaschine in einem Zustand \(\sigma\) dar.
Das Angebot wird angenommen, wenn in dem Zustand
\end{document}
```

On the left-hand side we see the output without `\babelposthyphenation{…}{…}{…}`, and on the right-hand side we see the output with `\babelposthyphenation{…}{…}{…}`:

[image: diffpdf output]

This shouldn't happen.

Comment: luatex manual says "The combined effect of these two differences is that LuaTEX does not always use all of the potential breakpoints in a paragraph, especially when fonts with many ligatures are used. Of course
kerning also complicates matters here." which could be clearer, but is I think warning of such things

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added `\showoutput` to the preamble of the example for “Zustandsmaschine” without `\babelposthyphenation…` but saw no ligatures on the standard output or in the log (or at least I didn't recognize the ligatures as such if there were any).

Comment: Discretionaries have several subtypes, and `babel` creates then with subtype ‘discretionary’ (value 0). Maybe it should be ‘regular’ (value 3). I have to investigate. Try editing the file `babel-transforms.lua`, from `d = node.new(7, 0)` to `d = node.new(7, 3)` (line ~367, depending on the version).

Comment: @JavierBezos Do I have to edit the installed file `babel-transforms.lua` (in my case, I can choose between the file from TeX Live shipped with Debian and an additional fresh installation of TeX Live) or does it suffice to make a local copy in the working directory?

Comment: @AlMa0 Either option should work, but I’m on Windows, so I can’t tell. Anyway, a new version will be available very shortly.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thanks! I confirm that putting a copy of the file `babel-transforms.lua` into the working directory and changing `d = node.new(7, 0)` to `d = node.new(7, 3)` in line 367 of this file removes the issues shown in the two small examples in my original post. Another good news is that if `\babelposthyphenation` is not invoked, your source-code change doesn't change the PDF output (except the meta-data, such as time stamps, of course).

Comment: @AlMa0  Glad to know.